# Миграция с MySql 5.1 на 5.7

Tags: mysql, миграция

Как правильно мигрировать с MySQL 5.1 на 5.7? Может есть готовые решения для миграции с разных версий на другие. Спасибо!

Comment: Что именно из официальной документации https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/upgrading.html осталось непонятым?

Comment: Лично не тестировал, но те кто попросил сделать миграцию говорят, что уже делали и все очень плохо работает. Поэтому ищу другое решение, где-то слышал, что можно написать свое на java. Вот и задал вопрос, может кто-то и поможет))

Comment: То есть Вы полагаете, что у Вас получится лучше, чем у профессионалов, для которых это основная работа? ну мнение имеет право на существование... Подкину только ещё одно (своё) мнение - всё там нормально. Правда, при условии, что инструкции по миграции выполняются с точностью до запятых и переводов строк. Минимальная невнимательность или лишняя инициатива - и  тут же *всё очень плохо*. PS. Рекомендую, если не уверены, начинать с Logical Upgrade.

Comment: Спасибо, да я тоже с Вами согласен и говорил об этом, но попросили еще какое-то решение.

Comment: Ну через текстовый дамп, скажем... вот только писАть для этого дела специальную программу явно не нужно, вполне можно обойтись одной командой для MySQLdump и небольшим SQL-скриптом.